# Can anyone help me on a kohana 3.1 route question?

Tags: routes, kohana-3

I'm trying to make a static route. I have a few controllers inside classes/controllers/admin/ but this one I want it to be on a separate module. The class is called Controller_filas and it rests on the module/filas/classes/controller dir.

I want that the url admin/filas route to /filas. Also I'll make a simple redirect if the user type /filas directly it redirect do admin/filas

```
Route::set('filas', 'admin/<controller>(/<action>)',
        array('controller'=> 'filas'))
        ->defaults(array('action'     => 'index'));
```

What's wrong with this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your other routes don't match admin/filas URL. Remember that routes are matched in the order they are added in bootstrap, so if one of the previous routes matched your URL, other routes will not be executed.
Your rule should work just fine. Make a simple test - comment all other routes leaving just this one and check if the route works.

Comment: but the controller is not on the admin dir. it's on is own dir under modules. do I have to put it into a admin dir there?

Comment: Sorry I omitted the information about controller being NOT in admin directory. I have edited the answer.